# Docker Pull Python

Tags: python-3.x, docker, web-scraping

I'm a beginner trying to user Docker with my python3 code.
This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM rdempsey/python-scraper:latest

ADD soj.py/

RUN pip3 install urllib.request

CMD [ "python", “./soj.py” ]
```

I got this error:

```
manifest for rdempsey/python-scraper:latest not found
```

So I assumed I need to do this Docker pull command:

```
docker pull rdempsey/python-scraper
```

In order to access this public repository https://hub.docker.com/r/rdempsey/python-scraper/ to fix the error.

I then experienced this error when trying to do the pull:

```
FrankieMacBook-Pro-2candidacy-job-slurper$ docker pull rdempsey/python-scraper
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for rdempsey/python-scraper:latest not found
```

Can someone direct me on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the image you are trying to pull does not contain a `latest` tag, only a `v2` tag.

Change the first line in your Dockerfile to `FROM rdempsey/python-scraper:v2` and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are pulling with latest tag which is not present at DockerHub. Try:

> docker pull rdempsey/python-scraper:v2

You can see the version at https://hub.docker.com/r/rdempsey/python-scraper/tags/

Answer (score 0):

Use a explicit version number (in this case v2) instead of the latest tag.